# Geocortex "Required parameter is null or empty"

Tags: gis

I am currently creating a workflow in which the user captures a point geometry by clicking on the map (this works), then the map zooms to the point's extent (this also works), and then buffers the point (this does not work).

My BufferTask activity gives me this: "Unhandled exception: 'Required parameter is null or empty. Parameter name: Geometry.SpatialReference in activity '1.3: BufferTask'"

This doesn't make sense to me since I have indeed entered a value for this parameter.

[image: Screenshot]

sidenote: Geocortex's documentation is virtually non-existent. My inner-cynic is telling me that this is on purpose so that you keep paying them to do things for you.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 best guesses would be either that the buffer spatial reference is null (the spatial reference used to actually create the buffer itself), or that the selectedLocation spatial reference is null for some reason.

For the first, see if there's a value entered for "Buffer Spatial Reference" which you'll see in the properties panel on the right side of the designer when you've got the Buffer Task selected. Note that using Web Mercator as the Buffer Spatial Reference will likely give you an inaccurate buffer due to distance distortion in that projection.

For the second, you could explicitly assign a SpatialReference to selectedLocation.SpatialReference using an assign activity (making sure that the assigned SpatialReference matches the actual spatial reference of your location).

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you specified a correct `spatialReference`, so the workflow module can assess the "length" of buffer. 
In addition isolate the problem.

Create a clean variable of type `spatialReference` and assign a `NEW SpatialRef(wkid)`. Then use that variable.

Comment: I'll try that. However, the way I have it set up is EXACTLY how their code example has it set up.